# Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module

Tags: angular

When I try to create a component in the angular cli, it's showing me this error. How do I get rid of it ?

> Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.

I'm using angular cli version: 1.4.1

Answer (score 1138, accepted):

Specify the module using the --module parameter. 
For example, if the main module is app.module.ts, run this:

```
ng g c new-component --module app
```

Or if you are in an other directory then

```
ng g c component-name --module ../
```

Comment: in my case it was 
`ng g c admin/manageUsers ---module ../app`

Comment: in my case i had to make sure i was in the app folder when doing it

Answer (score 151):

**Try This:** It is working for me

**`ng generate component componentName --module=app.module`**

Comment: Works for me. Thx. [Angular CLI: 1.7.4 // Node: 9.8.0 // OS: linux x64 // Angular: 5.2.9 ]

Comment: module = module name

Answer (score 74):

This is caused since the generation tried to add your component to a module, i.e. to add this line

```
import { MyComponent } from './Components/my-component/my-component.component';
```

but it found 2 modules.

As stated [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7439), they fixed it to a situation where as long as in the root src/app folder you have only 1 module, you're fine, so just ***move the secondaries modules to a sub-folder.***

Otherwise you have to use `--module`

Comment: This seems the most useful answer, saving you from having to specify the module all the time, thanks.

Comment: Yep. Moved my additional modules to a `modules` subfolder, and all is good now.

Comment: Thanks for remind, finally I found the second module: RoutingModule, and moved it to sub-folder

Answer (score 56):

It is working for me

```
ng g component component-name --skip-import
```

Comment: one important thing to note, is that this method dont automatically import these componets in the app.module.ts . So this has to be done manually.

Comment: Then you are forced to import manually. That's one very big bad recommendation that you gave. Mentioning the module is way much better!

Answer (score 34):

for me this command working:

```
ng g c new-component --module app
```

Answer (score 17):

There are two ways to solve this issue.

1) Skip (using --skip-import in command) default import and create component and once component is created import it manually wherever you want to use it.

```
ng generate component my-component --skip-import
```

2) Provide module name explicitly where you want it to be imported

```
ng generate  component  my-component --module=my-module.module
```

Answer (score 12):

Just a small update to Zisha's answer.

In my project all the modules were placed in a folder called "modules" and all the components are placed in "components" folder under "src/app"

[image: folder structure]

so to create a component under a specific path, I used the following syntax :

> ng g c components_path/component_name --module modules_path/module_name

example :

> ng g c components/login --module modules/app

Comment: I dunno, but, isn't a "better' design practice to place your components in their related modules?

Answer (score 10):

**Angular CLI: 6.0.8**
**Node: 10.4.0**
**OS: linux x64**
**Angular: 6.0.4**

In case there is a feature module (e.g. **manager.module.ts** inside the e.g. "/manager" sub-folder) with the routing module externalized into the separate NgModule (e.g. **manager-routing.module.ts**) the error message:

*More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.*

does not appear and the component is properly generated and added to the **manager.module.ts** module.

**BUT BE CAREFUL** the naming convention! the name of the routing module must terminate with "**-routing**"!

If the routing module is given a name like e.g. **manager-router.module.ts**, CLI will complain with the error message and expect you to provide --module option to automatically add the component import:

```
ng generate component some-name --module=manager.module.ts
```

or

```
ng generate component some-name --skip-import
```

if you prefer to add the import of the component manually

Comment: The `-` did the trick! I had `lib-name.routing.module.ts` instead of `lib-name-routing.module.ts`.

Answer (score 9):

> When app or lib have multiple nested modules

```
myApp
  > src
    > app
      app.module.ts
      > routes
        > login
          > auth
          login.module.ts
```

> Angular CLI

```
ng g component routes/login/auth/my-auth --module=routes/login/login.module.ts
```

> NRWL NX Angular CLI

```
ng g component routes/login/auth/my-auth --project=myApp --module=routes/login/login.module.ts
```

> Result

```
myApp
  > src
    > app
      app.module.ts
      > routes
        > login
          > auth
            > my-auth
              my-auth.component.ts etc...
          login.module.ts
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it seems ng is not registered into my environment path. I have been using npm run command to run the ng commands. Be aware in order to pass arguments you need an extra `--` as per the npm run specification.

Example:

```
npm run ng g c components/scheduling **--** --module=app
```

Or:

```
npm run ng g c components/scheduling **--** --skip-import
```

Comment: The two asterisks before and after the -- are not needed, but this did fix my problem, so thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting below error when trying to create a new component under a folder.

**error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.**

I have used below command and new component got created successfully under a folder.

```
 ng g c folderName/my_newComponent ---module ../app
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to give the specify module name like

```
ng g c your-component --module module-name
```

Where `module-name` should be that you want to update with newly created component.

Answer (score 4):

My project was created using Visual Studio Community 2017 and it creates 3 separated modules: app.browser.module, app.server.module and app.shared.module

In order to create my components I checked above answers and found my module to be app.shared.module.

So, I run:

```
ng g c componentName --module=app.shared.module
```

Answer (score 4):

When there is more than one module under app folder, generating a component with below command will fail:

```
ng generate component New-Component-Name
```

The reason is angular CLI detects multiple module, and does't know in which module to add the component. So, you need to explicitly mention which module component will be added:

```
ng generate component New-Component-Name --module=ModuleName
```

Answer (score 3):

> Angular CLI: 8.3.1

when you have multiple `module.ts` files inside a module, you need to specify for which module file you are generating component.

```
ng g c modulefolder/componentname --module=modulename.module
```

**for e.g.** i have shared module folder inside which i have `shared.module.ts` and `material.module.ts` like this

```
shared
  > shared.module.ts
  > material.module.ts
```

and i want to generate `sidebar` component for `shared.module.ts`
then i will run following command

```
ng g c shared/sidebar --module=shared.module
```

if you want to export the component then run following command

```
ng g c shared/sidebar --module=shared.module --export
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another piece of info to this for anyone like me who happens along that just has a single application.

I had my application set up with the main app.module.ts and I had routing with the routing module in it's own folder under the main application.  I went through and did some 'cleaning up' since I had a few other things that needed to be organized better.  One thing I did was move the routing.module.ts to the root folder; since it was the only file in the folder I figured it didn't need it's own folder.

This worked fine at first but next time I tried to generate a new component (some time later, through the WebStorm IDE) it failed with this message.  After reading through this I tried putting the routing module back into a separate folder and it worked again.

So note of warning to others, don't move the routing module into your root folder!  I'm sure there are other ways to deal with this too but I'm happy with it in it's own folder for now and using the IDE generator like I was previously.

Answer (score 3):

you have to mention only the module starting name before the .module extension

for example if your module name is **user-account.module.ts**
then in the command provide like

```
ng g c newComponent --module=user-account
```

Answer (score 2):

when you have more than one module, you need to specify module name

```
 ng g c componentName --module=modulename.module
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular CLI: 8.3.4
Node : 10.16.3
Angualr : 4.2.5

I used **"dotnet new angular"** command to generate the project, and it has generated 3 different modules in app folder (Although a simple test with **ng new project-name** just generates a single module.

see the modules in your project and decide wich module you want - then specify the name

```
ng g c componentName --module=[name-of-your-module]
```

You can read more about modules here:
https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules

Answer (score 2):

if you are creating in specific module go to that path and run 
ng g c componentname

else create module first
ng g module modulename

cd arc/app/modulename
go to modulename path and create the component

Answer (score 1):

try ng g component header --module app
it is work for me

Comment: works in angular 6. I moved the routes to `app.routing.module.ts` hence the error

Answer (score 1):

I had this warning when had this in `angular.json` config:

```
"prefix": "app_ng"
```

When changed to `"app"` all worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to create a standalone component in [Angular 16](https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-16#feature-highlights-in-angular-v16). so, you would not need to create the component into a given module.

```
ng generate component component-name --standalone
```

[Standalone components](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components), directives, and pipes are new features in Angular v16. So you can easily use components that are not tied to modules, like in other frameworks like React or Vue.

Answer (score 0):

As a hack, below steps, worked for me.

1) Move *.module.ts files from src/app to a location out of the project.

2) Execute command to create component `[ng g c component-name]`

3) Move back the *.module.ts files to src/app/

Comment: For this solution, check if the component is also registered in the relevant module. Running the command using the cli should do so. I guess the negative point has been because of this issue.