# angular 4 cli directive not working

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, directive

To create Directive in Angular 4 cli from git

/Angular/projectName $ ng generate directive DirectiveName

should work

[note : DirectiveName is unique not match with component name or module name]

but I am getting Error

Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.
More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46174863/error-more-than-one-module-matches-use-skip-import-option-to-skip-importing-th)

Comment: DV for lack of research

Comment: @Jota.Toledo thanks for your reply but you should read carefully the description before reply, look at the note.

Comment: The note makes no difference, the error is pretty clear and if you had googled its message you would have found the solution

Comment: component was working without any problem , the problem i found with the directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment CLI got confused to on step to insert `declarations` inside a *which* module, because you have more than one module in your application. You could append `skip-import` flag at the end of command. But that will skip importing & declaring component inside module.

I'd recommend to specify the `--module` in command where your directive should get declared.

```
ng generate directive DirectiveName --module="your-module.module.ts"
```